# NavBar kind of jerky (jQuery, html, css)

Tags: jquery, css, navbar, nav

I have a problem with my navbar being jerky from time to time. It doesn't happen all the time, which is funny but it bothers me when it does. The problem is when scrolling up/down at the beginning, it sometimes kind of lags on openning/closing. I'm using Google Chrome.

It's made using html, css and jquery. Here's the codepan link:
    https://codepen.io/JhnSnw/pen/prLwxa

I tried certain things i read online on similar issues, but they didn't work. Any kind of help is great. Thanks.

Comment: Why the downvotes? If your not an advanced user, the code looks fine. It requires knowledge about scroll events to even see the problem, let alone know how to fix it.  The "sometimes it works, sometimes it doesnt"kind of problems are difficult for beginners

Comment: You need to take another look in following things in your code.

1. In your codepen link, why there is script.java in the last line? This may not make menu look jerky though.

2. Download jquery to a local folder and use from there if you are not doing that. Your codepen has url of code.jquery.com. From a remote server, jquery load might be taking time, and the rendering of the page later might be appearing jerky.

3. Why are you handling window.scroll in your js when you are not trying to achieve anything purposeful from that?

Comment: I started web coding like few weeks ago (3 or smth like that). I am still learning and i'm sure there are certain things that could be done better. However, I'm really starting to love all of this and I want those things that are still bad to improve and make them look "pro" if you will.

Script java is there to make it work. Idk how else am I supposed to write codepen code when i can't (i think so) include folders from my PC or smth.

@Martijin thanks man, i'm trying to get better tho :)

Answer (score 0):

The window.scroll gets fired *for every scrolled pixel* (at least in Firefox), I'm guessing that might have some effect and your performace. To limit the amount of events, there is dethrottle, or deboucen.

[This webpage](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) has a nice plugin and explains it very well:

> A Visualization
>
> While $.throttle is designed to throttle callback execution, it behaves slightly differently based on how the no_trailing parameter is used.
>
> Throttled with no_trailing specified as false or unspecified:
> [image]

The first line is the amount of triggered event, the second line the detrottled version which might fire e.g. every 50ms (which is still very fast!).

---

The other solution you might apply, is a logic function. In your code, you have an if/else. If you scroll, you *always* apply `removeClass` or `addClass` which is not the best choice for performance.
You can easily remember wether or not your already past the threshold, and only fire when that changes again:

```
if (scrolled > navHeight){
    if( !scrolledPastThreshold ){
        $('.page-nav').addClass('off-canvas');
        scrolledPastThreshold = true;
    }
} else {
    if( scrolledPastThreshold ){
        $('.page-nav').removeClass('off-canvas');
        scrolledPastThreshold = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, i'll check that out for sure. Basically, you want to say it's not "my fault" in this coding?

Comment: It's not your fault, but it is your responsibility. You should fix this, especially now you know how to fix it.

Comment: Would you mind posting full jquery code, please? I'm little confused with this "scrolledPasThreshold".

Comment: that snippet is 95% done, all you need to do is add `scrolledPastThreshold = false` outside (before) your window.scroll.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I believe it looks better now, but I am going to test it few more times, like 1000 times haha. One thing that I also notice now is that my last line (border) of navbar (which always stays on screen on purpose) looks somehow dashed (or dotted) when the navbar goes up. Why would that happen, any idea?

Comment: This site isnt for followup question,, but you've set your top to -60px when `.off-canvas`, which is the height of the navbar. You should increase that, include the border and shadow

Comment: I put that on purpose like that. I want border (and shadow) to be there all the time. Visually looks better for me when there's a sign of navbar on screen.

Sry, i probably ask too much anyways.

Comment: I dont know. But if the problem you've asked is answered by my post, please mark as answered. If you like the answer, you can also upvote. Those two practices are normal on SO

Comment: I appreciate your help a lot. However, second option you gave me didn't solve my issue actually and i still haven't tried the first option about visualization (i need to understand it fully and i was busy today to do that). Therefore, i won't mark your post as answer because i don't want people to have wrong perception that i solved my issue. Anyways, i have upvoted your post as useful many times actually (prior to your "demand") but it won't show to you due to my reputation as only 12 (15 is required).

Again, thanks :)